# Seeing discoveryd error: Basic DNSResolver Return Code is 9 and we are treating it as an error!

Tags: dns, macos

Seeing this repeated pretty frequently in the Console logs for on my Macbook Pro running 10.10:

```
10/24/14 9:59:04.175 AM discoveryd[57]: Basic DNSResolver  Return Code is 9 and we are treating it as an error!
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: +1 I'm seeing this logged once per second on both my 10.10 machines (MacBook Air and my Mac Mini).  Would love to know what's causing it!

Comment: what does it show in your sys-pref-network-DNS ? (IP address?)

Comment: Do you still get this error on 10.10.2 / 14C109?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick although not a perfect solution my any means...

Primary DNS is the local machine -- Yosemite Server Running --
Other DNS are Google, OpenDNS, ISP

DHCP on the server... all other DHCP shut-off